# Get all non unique value more than one occurrence in array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

```
let input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    rollNo: 5,
    Name: "A",
    stDetails: {
      city: "city1",
      pin: 1234,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    rollNo: 5,
    Name: "B",
    stDetails: {
      city: "city1",
      pin: 1234,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    rollNo: 5,
    Name: "C",
    stDetails: {
      city: "city1",
      pin: 1234,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    rollNo: 5,
    Name: "D",
    stDetails: {
      city: "city1",
      pin: 1234,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    rollNo: 10,
    Name: "E",
    stDetails: {
      city: "city2",
      pin: 1234,
    },
  },
];
let uniqueKey = ["rollNo", "stDetails.city"];
```

I want to get the `id` of all non-unique values in more than one occurrence and to check record is unique we need to check by `rollNo` and `stDetails.city`

So the expected output is:

```
[{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}];
```

Here you can see `id` 2,3 and 4 have the same details as `id` 1 so that's why it is expected output

Comment: to read `stDetails.city` u need some extra logic like lodash get

Comment: @cmgchess can you give sample code?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/X83Bjj not sure if this is what u want

Answer (score 1):

### Pure JS Solution

Of course you can use libraries but pure ones are always the best!

You should loop through the `input` then save unique ones and compare each one to `uniques` array!

If you have trouble with comparison of objects, simply convert it to `JSON`!

Comment if you have questions...

```js
var input=[{"id":1,"rollNo":5,"Name":"A","stDetails":{"city":"city1","pin":1234}},
{"id":2,"rollNo":5,"Name":"B","stDetails":{"city":"city1","pin":1234}},
{"id":3,"rollNo":5,"Name":"C","stDetails":{"city":"city1","pin":1234}},
{"id":4,"rollNo":5,"Name":"D","stDetails":{"city":"city1","pin":1234}},
{"id":5,"rollNo":10,"Name":"E","stDetails":{"city":"city2","pin":1234}}
];

let unique_keys = ["rollNo", "stDetails"];
let uniques = [];
let non_uniques = [];
let uic;

for (let i of input) {
  for (let u of uniques) {
    uic = unique_keys.length;
    for (let uk of unique_keys) {
      let iitem = JSON.stringify(i[uk]);
      let uitem = JSON.stringify(u[uk]);
      if (iitem == uitem && --uic == 0) break;
    }
  }
  if (uic != 0) uniques.push(i);
  else non_uniques.push(i);
}

console.log(non_uniques);
```

**Notice: If you needed the unique ones, print the `uniques` array instead of `non_uniques` array.**

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input=[{"id":1,"rollNo":5,"Name":"A","stDetails":{"city":"city1","pin":1234}},
{"id":2,"rollNo":5,"Name":"B","stDetails":{"city":"city1","pin":1234}},
{"id":3,"rollNo":5,"Name":"C","stDetails":{"city":"city1","pin":1234}},
{"id":4,"rollNo":5,"Name":"D","stDetails":{"city":"city1","pin":1234}},
{"id":5,"rollNo":10,"Name":"E","stDetails":{"city":"city2","pin":1234}}
];
// Group by column rollNo & stDetails's city
var groupByCol=_.groupBy(input,function(x){return x.rollNo+'#'+x.stDetails.city});
var finaldata=[];
//Loop the record of grouping
_.forEach(groupByCol,function(c){
// If find match more than one then check.
if(c.length>1){
var finaldata=_.drop(_.map(c,function(x){return {"id":x.id}}))
console.log(finaldata);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can do it with this way.

Comment: lodash AND jQuery  seems a bit excessive for a fairly simple filter task

Comment: @MikeB It's depend on works if we think globally then it's easy to maintain & use it.

Comment: If you use pure JS (rather than a library) then there is no need for maintenance at all.

Comment: I think you are not understand what i want to tell you. Developer write shorter code & in pure js code we need to write whole logic which is some third party give us directly. When we think task as simple one then its fine but each & every task finally meet some big development at that point of time globally implement logic give us benefit of code reduce complexity of code & easy to use.